# Slider Revolution full width YouTube video layer

Tags: wordpress, video, youtube, slider

When I add a YouTube video as a slider background, it fits perfectly. No black bars on the sides. But when I add the same video as a layer and stretch it out, I can't get rid of the black bars to the left and right of it.

On wider screens, it's a chaos. The video only plays in a small section while black areas on the sides persist.

How can I inherit the dimensions of the background so that my YouTube video could play without those black bars on the sides?

I can't get use this video as a background because I want the sound to play. If there was a way to have sound within the background video, I wouldn't even have bothered putting the video as a layer.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Please indicate how you upload the video? Iframe, js youtube api, wordpress integreted method or plugin?

Comment: Hi, I use the slider revolution plugin and add the video as a slider layer. I select video slider --> YouTube video --> YouTube video id, and it's added. Thanks :)